# Remove default value of Material UI

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I am learning NextJS as well as Material UI. I have a Form. Code of Email and PassWord field of the Form is like below.

```
<TextField
  label="Email"
  variant="outlined"
  type="email"
  required
/>

<TextField
  label="Password"
  variant="outlined"
  type="password"
  required
/>
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

I would like to remove these Default Values.

How can I remove those Default Values?

Comment: @NearHuscarl, Actually I am learning Material UI. I am also searching these values in Whole Code. Which code should I add ?

Comment: isnt browser auto complete?

Comment: @Nico, Thanks. May be you are correct.

Comment: @abuabu you can remove the `type` attribute and reload the page, if it doesn't fill then it's indeed the autocompletion from the browser.